# Implement "Remember Me" Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm currently trying to implement "Remember Me" feature in Django.

I'm using both `SessionAuthentication` from Django REST framework and `JSONWebTokenAuthentication` from djangorestframework-jwt.

However, I don't know how to implement the concept of "Remember Me" for these two authentications. Like how do I extend the session forever and how do I extend the token forever (I'm using JWT auth for mobile & desktop - Session auth for browser).

Also, what is the secure way to implement this feature for both authentications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things here that I should make clear ahead of time: how authentication works and where expiration comes into play for `SessionAuthentication` and `JSONWebTokenAuthentication`.

### Session Authentication

The `SessionAuthentication` class provided by Django REST framework is really just small layer over the [session framework provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/). So if you can implement a "remember me" function in Django using their sessions, DRF will also inherit it.

Luckily, someone already asked about that on Stack Overflow: [Django “Remember Me” with built-in login view and authentication form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15100400/359284)

Basically it comes down to changing [the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE) (2 weeks by default) to a very high number. Also make sure to keep in mind the implications of having long-lived sessions, and perhaps check out how long the session cookies are by default on websites you visit (typically anywhere from 2 weeks to 6 months).

### JSON Web Tokens

The `JSONWebToken` authentication class provided by [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) authenticates requests based on JSON Web Tokens. By default, tokens expire in five minutes but can be refreshed for up to seven days.

The token expiration time is controlled by the `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA` setting. It is not recommended to extend this time too large, but instead [use refresh tokens](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#refresh-token) for long-lived tokens. You can enable refresh tokens with the `JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH` setting and control the expiration time with the `JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA` setting.

Comment: So for mobile or desktop app talking to the server using JWT, should I store the username and password in local database and keep requesting token for 'Remember Me' feature? Or should I just save the token, but use expiration time like 1 day and keep refreshing?

Comment: @TimNguyen I'd _highly recommend_ storing the refresh token in the local database. Storing their username and password in plain text (or even lightly encrypted) is risky, storing an easily revocable token with an expiration is _not as risky_.

Comment: django-rest-framework-jwt won't give me a refresh_token and that's driving me crazy! I am setting `JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH` property as True and setting `JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA` for a long long time. The behaviour I expect is to be given a `refresh_token` but that is not happening. The one token I get does not work for token refreshing after the `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA` is reached. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

In setting file you have to set:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

In template :

provide a checkbox with name="remember_me" value="1"

In login function (view.py or ajax.py) write this code when username and password matches,

```
try:
    remember = request.POST['remember_me']
    if remember:
        settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
except MultiValueDictKeyError:
    is_private = False
    settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

Comment: Not sure it is a good idea to modify settings live. Settings are supposed to be global constants.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard is right. Settings should not be modified from code.

Comment: This code wouldn't just change the settings for your one client but for your whole server.

Answer (score -1):

## Dependencies

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from site_user.models import User
```

## This code will revoke username and password from session when we are at login page

```
def home(request):
    if request.session.has_key('username') and request.session.has_key('password'):
        username = request.session['username']
        password = request.session['password']
        context_dict = {'username': username, 'password': password}
        return render(request, 'sadmin/login.html', context=context_dict)
    else:
        context_dict = {'username': '', 'password': ''}
        return render(request, 'sadmin/login.html', context=context_dict)
```

## The following code is used for user authentication. Here 'is_remember_check' checkbox field from HTML file

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST['is_remember_check'] == 'true':
            request.session['username'] = request.POST['username']
            request.session['password'] = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])

        if user is not None:
            return JsonResponse({'result': request.POST, 'status': True})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'result': request.POST, 'status': False})
```

## AJAX call from login page

```
function login(){
    remember_checkbox_value = document.getElementsByName('remember')[0].checked;
    username = document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value;
    password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value;
    var post_data = {username:username, password:password, is_remember_check:remember_checkbox_value};

    $.ajax({
                url: '/sadmin/login/',
                method: 'POST',
                data: post_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                        if (response.status){
                        alert("User login is successful");
                        window.location.reload();
                        }
                        else{
                        alert("User login is not successful");
                        window.location.reload();
                        }
                }
        });
}
```

## HTML Code

```
<div class="form-actions">
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember"/> Remember me </label>
            <button type="button" class="btn green-haze pull-right" onclick="login()">Login <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
```